# Generate <a> link in controller to send in email

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, hyperlink, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm implementing a password reset system, and while the code is working fine, there's a small problem... with the users. The system works by generating single-use crypto-secure tokens which are sent via email. The problem is that to use these tokens, the user must then click on a link in the email they receive. This in itself isn't a problem, but the link in question looks something like this:

```
http://www.example.com/Account/ResetPassword/184?t=BC2EveZtRl3wjbONboalzlUVwUpp%252BYaiKvbsZ6aPPYE%253D
```

The users are reluctant to click on this link because it's big and scary-looking; they think it's a trick by some malicious third party to steal their password or give them a virus or something.

If this was a view, I'd use `@Html.ActionLink()` to generate a pretty `<a>` link that said "Click here to reset your password", and that'd be fine. In a controller, however, I don't have access to that method unless I instantiate a `HtmlHelper`, which requires `ViewData`, which leads to a whole chain of things that need to be instantiated to fake up some stuff that I won't use anyway, and everywhere I've looked says that this is bad practice and I shouldn't do it.

What's the cleanest way to generate a neat `<a>` link, in controller code, in ASP.NET MVC?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `UrlHelper` is available in a controller via the `Url` property, that can do the same thing, and that is to build a url for you. So you can feed your email sender a text that include a link and this is how you build that part of the email:

```
var link = "<a href='http://www.mysite.com/" 
    + @Url.Action("ResetPassword","Account", new{id=184, t=token}) 
    +"'>Click here to reset your password</a>"
// where token is your single-use crypto-secure
```

If you want the domain to be dynamic then you can change it to:

```
var link = "<a href='" 
    + Request.Url.Scheme + "://"
    + Request.Url.Authority
    + @Url.Action("ResetPassword","Account", new{id=184, t=token}) 
    +"'>Click here to reset your password</a>"
// where token is your single-use crypto-secure
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Asp.NET Core 2.0 or above, then you can use the [Url.Page()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.urlhelperextensions.page?view=aspnetcore-2.0) method to generate the link.

```
var link = Url.Page("/Account/ResetPassword", new{id=184, t=token}, Request.Scheme);
```